# Standard-complying method to do unit test-style script registration?

Tags: c++, global-variables, language-lawyer, program-entry-point, undefined-behavior

I wish to implement a script-loading system in C++ using a pattern similar to what's used in popular testing libraries, such as Google Test and Catch2. Commonly for the user, this looks as follows:

```cpp
TEST(Testname) {
   // Some function code
}
```

Which can be invoked ad-hoc in just about any source file, and thus possibly in any arbitrary TU. At least for Catch2, this seems to be implemented by doing something along the lines of first declaring the function, then forcing a global variable to initialize to a registry that stores this function, and then starting an implementation of it. As a (greatly simplified) macro:

```
#define TEST(name) \
    void name(); \
    auto name##Initializer = RegisterFunction(name); \
    void name() 

// ^ -- where the following block becomes the function body of the test.
```

[More specifically the implementation I've looked at](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/4436a604566f18091489b55af215b8d32afe657a/src/catch2/internal/catch_test_registry.hpp#L75)

I was planning on having a library using a similar style, with a registry function as follows to avoid initialization order fiasco. To keep it simple, i'll just pretend that I'm writing a testing library:

```cpp
std::vector<TestType> & tests() {
    static std::vector<TestType> _tests;
    return _tests;
}

int RegisterFunction(TestType test) {
   tests().push_back(test);
   return 0;   
}
```

So that I may access this in my main function as such:

```cpp
int main()
{
   for(auto const& test: tests()
   {
       // handle all registered test cases
   }
}
```

On my compiler, this works as expected. However, I've found the following quoted frequently in discussions around global variable initialization:

> [basic.start.init]/4: It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

To me, it would *seem* I can be standard compliant here by marking my `auto name##Initializer = ...` as "inline" despite 0 external functions calling this translation unit. I'm not too familiar with more esoteric uses of C++ like this one, so I'm still nervous this is somehow relying on UB. Assuming I'm doing all the RegistryFunction fluff correctly, am I correct that the standard promises the program will initialize all my variables and force the registration of all my functions, in any translation unit, before "main" is called? If not, do testing libraries just rely on UB to do this or am I missing something about their implementation?

Comment: Not too surprising, but then how do testing libraries ensure this? Do they just not do that and instead rely on massive hacks in the compilers? I've only really tested msvc and gcc, and was initially surprised it does seem to work for them

Comment: (it appears the comment I previously responded to has disappeared)

Comment: In case this shows up in a search engine, the way I've opted to solve/hack this is to use cmake scripts to regex my files for my version of the `TEST` macro, generate a header accessing all `name##Initializer` variables via externs and then print them out through a function that `main` calls, forcing the compiler to initialize them and hopefully avoiding any possibility of anything being optimized away. For my purposes, this is good enough, as my biggest concern is compatibility rather than edge-case regexes breaking or not allowing namespaces.